# Getting access to media player cache

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to move a progressively streamed mp3 file to sd card once it is completely loaded. Is there any way of achieving that.

I've seen that the `MediaPlayer` completely downloads the whole file while progressive streaming and then we can seek to any part of file. I want to move a fully streamed file to external storage so that future playback do not waste data and battery.

Comment: Best answer here, if anybody still looks for solution: 

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/12044709/1548464

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment on the original post points you in the right direction, but I thought it may be helpful to expound a bit...

What I've done is build a lightweight proxy server using the Apache HTTP libraries. There should be plenty of examples out there to get the basics of this part. Provide the MediaPlayer an appropriate localhost URL so that it opens a socket to your proxy. When the MediaPlayer makes a request, use the proxy to send an equivalent request to the actual media host. You will receive byte[] data in the proxy's packetReceived method, which I use to build an HttpGet and send it on its way with AndroidHttpClient.

You will get back an HttpResponse and you can use the HttpEntity inside to access the streaming byte data. I'm using a ReadableByteChannel, like so:

```
HttpEntityWrapper entity = (HttpEntityWrapper)response.getEntity();
ReadableByteChannel src = Channels.newChannel(entity.getContent());
```

Do whatever you'd like with the data as you read it back (like cache it in a file on the SD card). To pass the correct stuff on to the MediaPlayer, get the SocketChannel from the client Socket, first write the response headers directly to that channel, and then proceed to write the entity's byte data. I'm using an NIO ByteBuffer in a while loop (client is a Socket and buffer is a ByteBuffer).

```
int read, written;
SocketChannel dst = client.getChannel();
while (dst.isConnected() &&
    dst.isOpen() &&
    src.isOpen() &&
    (read = src.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
    try {
        buffer.flip();
        // This is one point where you can access the stream data.
        // Just remember to reset the buffer position before trying
        // to write to the destination.
        if (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            written = dst.write(buffer);
            // If the player isn't reading, wait a bit.
            if (written == 0) Thread.sleep(15);
            buffer.compact();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

You may need to alter the host header in the response before passing it along to the player so that it looks like your proxy is the sender, but I'm dealing with a proprietary implementation of the MediaPlayer so behaviour could be a bit different. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you share some more code on how to create the proxy and intercept the data??

Comment: how can we intercept  the mediaplayer request?

Answer (score 19):

The idea is to create a proxy that the media player can read from, instead of reading data directly from the web.

I used [danikula/AndroidVideoCache](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache) which is very simple to build/use.
I used it for Audio not Video, but its just the same.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Direct and easy to use. I wish I could give 10 votes.

Comment: How can I encrypt cache file?

Answer (score 5):

Its late but i found that most of the people still need a solution. My solution based on [JakeWharton's DiskLruCache](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache).
We need two things

- AsyncTask to read file or download from network and cache it
- Callback to get InputStram/FileDescriptor from cache

**Step 1:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

// you can use FileDescriptor as 
// extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FileDescriptor>

public class AudioStreamWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FileInputStream> {

    private OnCacheCallback callback = null;
    private Context context = null;

    public AudioStreamWorkerTask(Context context, OnCacheCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected FileInputStream doInBackground(String... params) {
        String data = params[0];
        // Application class where i did open DiskLruCache
        DiskLruCache cache = MyApplication.getDiskCache(context);
        if (cache == null)
            return null;
        String key = hashKeyForDisk(data);
        final int DISK_CACHE_INDEX = 0;
        long currentMaxSize = cache.getMaxSize();
        float percentageSize = Math.round((cache.size() * 100.0f) / currentMaxSize);
        if (percentageSize >= 90) // cache size reaches 90%
            cache.setMaxSize(currentMaxSize + (10 * 1024 * 1024)); // increase size to 10MB
        try {
            DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = cache.get(key);
            if (snapshot == null) {
                Log.i(getTag(), "Snapshot is not available downloading...");
                DiskLruCache.Editor editor = cache.edit(key);
                if (editor != null) {
                    if (downloadUrlToStream(data, editor.newOutputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX)))
                        editor.commit();
                    else
                        editor.abort();
                }
                snapshot = cache.get(key);
            } else
                Log.i(getTag(), "Snapshot found sending");
            if (snapshot != null)
                return (FileInputStream) snapshot.getInputStream(DISK_CACHE_INDEX);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(getTag(), "File stream is null");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(FileInputStream fileInputStream) {
        super.onPostExecute(fileInputStream);
        if (callback != null) {
            if (fileInputStream != null)
                callback.onSuccess(fileInputStream);
            else
                callback.onError();
        }
        callback = null;
        context = null;
    }

    public boolean downloadUrlToStream(String urlString, OutputStream outputStream) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(urlString);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            // you can use BufferedInputStream and BufferOuInputStream
            IOUtils.copy(stream, outputStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
            Log.i(getTag(), "Stream closed all done");
            return true;
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null)
                IOUtils.close(urlConnection);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private String getTag() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    private String hashKeyForDisk(String key) {
        String cacheKey;
        try {
            final MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            mDigest.update(key.getBytes());
            cacheKey = bytesToHexString(mDigest.digest());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            cacheKey = String.valueOf(key.hashCode());
        }
        return cacheKey;
    }

    private String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aByte : bytes) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aByte);
            if (hex.length() == 1)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(hex);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

```
public interface OnCacheCallback {

    void onSuccess(FileInputStream stream);

    void onError();
}
```

**Example**

```
final String path = "http://www.example.com/test.mp3";
new AudioStreamWorkerTask (TestActivity.this, new OnCacheCallback() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(FileInputStream fileInputStream) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".MediaPlayer", "now playing...");
    if (fileInputStream != null) {
        // reset media player here if necessary
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
            mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".MediaPlayer", "fileDescriptor is not valid");
    }
}

@Override
public void onError() {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName() + ".MediaPlayer", "Can't play audio file");
}
}).execute(path);
```

**Note:**

This is tested but rough sample for audio file caching, there may be some problems if you find anything please inform me :)

Comment: what you mean by this `// Application class where i did open DiskLruCache`

Comment: Initialize DiskLruCache in your Application class (extends with Application), or where ever you want :)

Comment: If you can show me the piece of code how you have written the initialization of DiskLruCache. thank you

Comment: DiskLruCache diskLruCache = DiskLruCache.open(getCacheDir(), 1, 1, 50 * 1024 * 1024);