# Android MediaPlayer - Downloading and Streaming at same time revisited

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-2.2-froyo

This question has been asked before, but now with the newer versions of Android (up to Jelly Bean), I was wondering if there's been any progress on downloading AND streaming a file at the same time. From the API, it doesn't look like it's inherently possible, as these are the available setDataSource methods:

```
void    setDataSource(String path)
Sets the data source (file-path or http/rtsp URL) to use.
void    setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers)
Sets the data source as a content Uri.
void    setDataSource(Context context, Uri uri)
Sets the data source as a content Uri.
void    setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)
Sets the data source (FileDescriptor) to use.
void    setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)
Sets the data source (FileDescriptor) to use.
```

Unfortunately it does not accept an InputStream of any kind.  There are examples that use the old NPR proxy code that opens a local web server in the Android App, downloads content remotely, and outputs requested data to any listening sockets, however that code is more than 2 years old and it's still used as the standard for accomplishing this task (even though a lot of people report that there are stuttering issues, etc).

I've looked into the MediaPlayer class and wanted to extend it to allow this behaviour however a lot of the implementation is accomplished through native code, and from what I've read, different device manufacturers implement the native audio functionality differently (and if so, I don't want to touch it! :) ).

So, **what is the best method to store AND concurrently stream incoming audio data (MP3 or OGG) from a remote server**, without discarding the data? Preferably with versions of Android 2.2 and above, but input on any available API would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building a local proxy is your best bet. I haven't looked at the NPR example, but I've done similar. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701249/getting-access-to-media-player-cache).