# Streaming audio file and caching it

Tags: android, caching, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I want to **stream an audio mp3 file and then play it through android media player** plus I also **want to cache this file**, so that mediaplayer don't have to stream for recently played tracks.

I have tried using `prepareAsync` method but it doesn't give me access to buffer content, so I have decided to stream the audio file myself and then pass it to the media player for playing. I have achieved this by following this article **[here](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)** but this approach has a problem i.e. while transferring the file to media player it goes into error mode which causes my player to behave inconsistently.

When media player enters its error mode it doesn't come out of it automatically so I am forced to create a new media player and then re-provide it the downloaded file, this workaround causes the user to experience an undesired pause in the song playing.

So, does any one have improved an version of code given in above [link](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)? **or** do they know a better solution to this problem **or** is there is actually a library for streaming an audio file in android?

Thanks

Comment: From a `MediaPlayer` point of view, the input source abstracted as `DataSource` should be capable of working in pull model. From your comment above, the `MediaPlayer` will pull the data from your streaming source. Can you confirm that your source supports a pull mode of operation? Can you share the errors faced by you?

Comment: @Ganesh i am not familiar of pull model can you explain it or can you mention any link which implements or explains media player pull model

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided looks like a less than ideal solution (not to mention outdated). What you probably want is a local proxy server that gives you access to byte data before the `MediaPlayer` gets it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701249/getting-access-to-media-player-cache/18627606#18627606) for a little more explanation.