# Caching audio stream while playing it in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, audio-streaming, offline-caching

I am looked at several audio *libs*, that support play audio file by url 
,but no one give access to audio data, so that i can cache it while playing.

So my question is - **Can i cache streaming audio data to file in device?**

I found another way in native android

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701249/getting-access-to-media-player-cache/18627606#18627606)

That using intermediate proxy server on device instead of directly download from url, so you have access to audio data and you can write in in file parallel with play.
But i need do this using flutter.