# How to start playing audio from file, that is still downloading?

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, android-mediaplayer

How to start playing audio from file, that is still downloading with Android MediaPlayer. After click of the play button I need to start download audio file from URL and play it at the same time. Can MediaPlayer do that? I think, I need to start playing from URL and the same time start download file. When file will be downloaded I think that I need to create URI of downloaded file and reset MediaPlayer with the new data source - URI of downloaded file.

Comment: How about ExoPlayer?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer

Comment: @tancolo i see that player but my app using media player already. Maybe i can start download file and create byte array for this file? But i don't know can byte array modifing in run-time?

Comment: I searched it on stackoverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041994/progressive-audio-caching-library-for-android  maybe it's helpful to you.